# If Remote Desktop minimize or close c# form application stopped

Tags: c#, forms, clipboard, screen-capture

I wrote a program using c# with form application, using clipboard and capture screen. This program running remote desktop (mstsc). But if I close remote desktop window (not disconnect only close window or minimize window) my program is stopping.

I didn't find any solution. Can you help me please

> Error:stack trac location:
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY,
>   Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize)
>
> Error:message The handle is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Your program stops because it is not able to take the screen shot (which is what your exception shows).

This is because, **[when you are on a remote session there is not screen](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/74e789ea-160b-4b89-8296-3274d1bff1de)**, the screen is in fact the screen where you opened the session from (your screen), so when you close or you minimize the *mstsc* window your remote session does not have a screen anymore.

Try to handle the exception so your application does not finish completely (try.catch block for instance).